# Identifier Unidentified in Default Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, queue, identifier, std-pair

I've been searching online a lot for how to fix this. Also tried making everything public, but I don't think that's the problem. Here's my header code:

```
#ifndef DEALER_HPP
#define DEALER_HPP

#include <queue>

class Dealer{
private:
    queue<pair<int, char>> deck;

public:
    Dealer(); // default constructor
    ~Dealer(); // destructor        
};

#endif
```

Source file:

```
#include "Dealer.hpp"

using namespace std;

Dealer::Dealer(){// create unshuffled deck
    const char* suitValue[4] = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};

    for (int i = 2; i <= 14; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            deck.push(pair<int, char> (i, suitValue[j])); // error on this line
        }
    }
}
```

I've got an error in my source file,

> identifier "deck" is unidentified.

Any idea how to fix it? I've also tried using make_pair with no success. I really feel like the code I have should be working, I'm sure there's some simple mistake. Sorry, I'm having trouble chasing this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need `#include <utility>` and the declaration of `deck` should be:

```
std::queue< std::pair<int, char> > deck;
```

This is probably the source of your error, although there should also have been an error message for this specific line.

Moving on, the pair is a pair of `int` and `char`. But you write later:

```
pair<int, char> (i, suitValue[j])
```

`suitValue[j]` is a `char *`, not a `char`. So this also must generate a compiler error. I guess you want `std::string` instead of `char` and `const char *` in both places.

Also, you access out of bounds in the `j` loop. For an array of dimension `4`, the valid indices are `0` `1` `2` `3`. Not `4`.